# Is there an inverse of fromNodeCallback?

Tags: bacon.js

Is there something in bacon.js that converts back to a node callback, like Q does with it's node adapters? https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node

Comment: What do you mean by "back to a node callback", can you show an example of how you'd like to use this? Where exactly does Q do this; it only offers methods to convert nodeback-methods to promise methods?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to invoke node-style callback when there is value on stream ?

```
stream.onValue(function(val) {
    callback(null, val);
}).mapError(callback);
```

There is no convenience function in Bacon to do that (or I didn't noticed that), but it's so small piece of code, that you can do it by yourself. Note that I have used onValue, because you need at least one consumer, however if you are consuming stream elsewhere, you can do it simply like this:

```
stream.map(callback.bind(null, null)).mapError(callback);
```

Edit:

If you need to support multiple arguments to the callback that are delivered in the array from the stream, it would look like this:

```
stream.onValue(function(values) {
    callback.apply(null, null, values);
});
```